# Problem with spatie/laravel-menu and spatie/laravel-persmissions

Tags: php, laravel, menu, laravel-permission

I'm using spatie/laravel-menu and spatie/laravel-persmissions in my laravel project.

I have created a permission, assigned it to a role, and assigned the role to my user. This works fine. 
Then I have generated a menu the middleware way using a macro like so:

```
\Menu::macro('main', function () use ($request) {
    return \Menu::new()
        ->withoutWrapperTag()
        ->withoutParentTag()
        ->setActiveClassOnLink()
        ->route('preparation', 'Anstehende Termine')
        ->route('postprocessing', 'Nachbereitung')
        ->routeIfCan('administrate', 'protocols', 'Protokolle')
        ->addItemClass('nav-link')
        ->setActive($request->url());
});
```

In my application I have two User models with different connections:
`App\User;` using connection_a with database db_a and
`App\DirectoryA\User;` using connection_b with database db_b

In the auth config the first one is defined, and using `Auth::user()->can('administrate')` works fine, even in the Middleware that defines the menu.

Since I have added the menu item via `routeIfCan`, I'm getting an error. It tells

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_b.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select `permissions`.*, `model_has_permissions`.`model_id` as `pivot_model_id`, `model_has_permissions`.`permission_id` as `pivot_permission_id`, `model_has_permissions`.`model_type` as `pivot_model_type` from `permissions` inner join `model_has_permissions` on `permissions`.`id` = `model_has_permissions`.`permission_id` where `model_has_permissions`.`model_id` = 1 and `model_has_permissions`.`model_type` = App\User)

What is going wrong here? It should use the `App\User` model. Placing a `dd()` at the point the framework throws the exception shows me the correct connection...

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A member of spatie helped to solve the problem:

> Under the hood, routeIfCan calls app(Gate::class)->allows($ability, $ablityArguments). I assume Gate behaves slightly different than Auth::user() when it comes to multiple guards.
>   I don't see much room in routeIfCan to add an additional $guard or $connection argument, so I suggest you use $menu->addIf(Auth::user()->can('administrate'), ...) instead.

Answer (score 0):

this mean table `permissions` not exist on your database maybe you forgot to run `php artisan migrate` after install [laravel-permission](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/installation-laravel/)?

Comment: Yes, I ran ```php artisan migrate```. 
But as you can see in the error description, it uses the wrong database - db_b. This database belongs to the second user with the second connection and database (```App\DirectoryA\User```). Instead it should use the first one (```App\User```) with the correct connection and database. In this database the ```permissions``` table exists.

Comment: hmm i never try to connect 2 diferent database in one project,default `migration` will run on db you defind in `.env` but if you have multiple database connection may you need edit migration check [this tutorial](https://medium.com/teknomuslim/how-to-run-laravel-using-multiple-database-connections-d7e8dcb7ed2a) , make 2 connection on `.env` and edit `migration` to set spesific connection or if you cannot fix by code in laravel just copy the missing table to another database you want

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to specify the connection for the migrations, because there is specified a default connection. Apart from this the tables are in the right place - the default connection. Everything uses the default connection, except at this point. 

In the auth config the first model of the two mentioned above is defined as default, too. 
It is frustrating...

Comment: I meant "not necessary to specify the connection for the migrations" ...

Comment: I checked the tutorial, but I did not find anything that could help.

Comment: well maybe you want create missing table without migration

Comment: The migration of the tables to the correct database was successfull, but later on the error occurs during usage.